# Copying data from one sheet to another using Excel VBA loops (within the same workbook)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to Copy data from one sheet (SheetA) to another sheet (sheetB). I've set up a loop that copies the data and pastes it successfully. However, it pastes the data to SheetB in whatever row it was held in on SheetA (i.e. if the data came from Row 12 it would be pasted in Row 12 - I want it to be pasted in the next available row to avoid any blank rows).

The code currently looks like this - I've tried adding a counting variable (w) for the destination but this won't work (quite amateur) as you can probably tell:

```
w = 1
x = 1

RawData.Activate
    Do While Cells(x, 4).Value <> ""
            If Cells(x, 4).Value = "Bracknell" Then
            RawData.Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 10)).Copy Destination:=Bracknell.Range("A" & w)
        End If

x = x + 1
w = w + 1

Loop
```

Cheers in advance guys!

Comment: You need to move `w = w + 1` before the `End If`.

Comment: If the are already filled cells, replace `w = 1` with `w = Bracknell.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row` and move `w = w + 1` before the `End If`, as SJR suggested.

Comment: @FaneDuru you need a `+ 1` after the `.row` on that, else it will replace the last cell with data.

Comment: @Damian: Yes, or add 1 when `w` is defined...

Comment: Lovely stuff thanks guys! Some time penalty (5sec is now 35sec run time but I can work it out)